# How to find all occurrences(index) of an sublist in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I know how to find all occurrences of an element in a list:

```
my_list  = ["foo", "bar", "baz","foo", "bar", "baz"]
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x == "bar"]
```

so it can return:

```
[1, 4]
```

so if I want to find the index of a list, how to do that?

I tried to :

```
my_list  = ["foo", "bar", "baz","foo", "bar", "baz"]
sub_list = ["bar", "baz"]
for k in sub_list:
    indices.append([i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x == k])
```

print(indices)
but only return
[[1, 4], [2, 5]]
how to correct it to [1,2,4,5]?

Comment: Use `extend` instead of `append`. And then sort if you want it in ascending numerical order.

Comment: @HS-nebula Hi, there, I can mark your reply if you write your answer below:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you append the list comprehension statement that matches indices for each item in `sub_list`, you append them as lists of indices. `append` will add the sublist to the `indices` list as an element. That's why you're getting results as a list of lists.

If you take the loop out of the list comprehension you can see this more clearly

```
my_list  = ["foo", "bar", "baz","foo", "bar", "baz"]
sub_list = ["bar", "baz"]
indices = []
for k in sub_list:
    for i, x in enumerate(my_list):
        if x == k:
            indices.append(i)

print(indices)
# [1, 4, 2, 5]
```

However, there's an alternative method you can use to the loop, `extend`, which adds the elements of the iterable sublist to the `indices` list.

```
my_list  = ["foo", "bar", "baz","foo", "bar", "baz"]
sub_list = ["bar", "baz"]
indices = []
for k in sub_list:
    indices.extend([i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x == k])

print(indices)
# [1, 4, 2, 5]
```

Using `extend` is also faster for larger lists (multiply `my_list` by 100 and using `%%timeit` gives 65.8 us for the first method and 54.7 us using `extend`).

Answer (score 0):

to get the index of your list you can make it:

```
my_list  = ["foo", "bar", "baz","foo", "bar", "baz"]
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x == "bar"]

print(indices)
```

to join 2 lists:

```
listone = [1,2,3]
listtwo = [4,5,6]

joinedlist = listone + listtwo
```

and if you need a merged list of only unique values:

```
mergedlist = list(set(listone + listtwo))
```

if you wana read more look into:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_join_lists.asp